# Fixing a bug in a ternary-like if-else block

Tags: swift

Instead of using the ternary operator, I coded a if-else block which doesn't seem to compile... Didn't understand the bug exactly, why isn't it working? Error line is :

> error: MyPlayground2.playground:6:1: error: variables currently must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL
>   var parentAge: Int

And my code:

```
import UIKit



var parent: String = "mom"
var parentAge: Int
let optOne = 39
let optTwo = 43

if parent == "mom" {
    parentAge = optOne
    print(parentAge)
} else {
    parentAge = optTwo
    print(parentAge)
}
```

Comment: Your `parentAge` needs to have an initial value. Set it to any integer value, because it's going to replaced anyway. Or make it an _optional_ `!`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesha, it seems to work. The think I don't understand is the example in the Apple course book has no predefined value. 

'“var largest: Int
 
let a = 15
let b = 4
 
if a > b {
  largest = a
} else {
  largest = b
}”

Excerpt From: Apple Education. “App Development with Swift.” Apple Inc. - Education, 2017. iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/tr/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996?mt=11' @RakeshaShastri

Comment: Well, then as you can see they are wrong! :'D There is probably more context to your example. That link did not show me any page with code btw.

Comment: @BerkeTurer: That is (as the referenced answer explains) just a restriction of *Playgrounds.* Your code is valid Swift, and compiles without problems in a “real” Xcode project.

Comment: @MartinR in a real Xcode project, if it declared outside any class he would still need to set an initial value or mark it optional?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: No. A variable must be assigned a value *before it is used.* You can easily verify that the above code compiles and runs in an Xcode project.

Comment: @MartinR How come it throws the error _"Global 'var' declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter specifier"_ ?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: Put it into  “main.swift” of a command-line project.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thanks a lot for both answering and referencing the answer.

Comment: @MartinR wow! Thanks, that one comment taught me a lot just now. I'd never done a [command line project](https://medium.com/quick-code/lets-build-a-command-line-app-in-swift-328ce274f1cc) till now.

Answer (score 0):

> error: variables currently must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL

You should either initialise it with `optional` or assign an initial value if not optional.

```
var parentAge: Int?

var parentAge: Int = 0
```

Both of above representation are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ankit, but I guess the error is about Playgrounds rather than the code itself, as Martin R mentioned above.